# AutoMapper ResolveUsing not being invoked

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a mapping where I currently use `MapFrom` and everything works as expected.

I am trying to replace the `MapFrom` with a `ResolveUsing` and I'm finding that my resolve function is simply not called. It is as if the code doesn't exist (when trying class form with a breakpoint in the constructor, it is not hit).

```cs
// This works as expected
CreateMap<Contact, ContactListViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, map =>
        map.MapFrom(s => s.RelationshipTypeId == Relationship.SELF ? s.Person.FirstName : s.FirstName))

// This doesnt. Resolver never invoked  
CreateMap<Contact, ContactListViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());

// Example resolver 
public class CustomResolver : IValueResolver<object, object, string>
{
    public CustomResolver()
    {
        // never called
    }

    public string Resolve(object source, object destination, string member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return ... // never invoked
    }
}
```

This seems pretty basic and I do have other mappings where I successfully use ResolveUsing. Any ideas on how I can go about debugging this and determine why my mappings are being ignored?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, using AutoMapper 10.1.1 with C# 9's records;

NOTE: The `.ResolveUsing<>` method is not available anymore, it has been replaced by the generic `MapFrom<>` method;

I was trying to map one record into another. The destination record had a constructor:

`record Record(string Property)`

The solution in my case was to call `.ConstructUsing()` after all the `.ForMember()` invocations.

The final mapping would look this:

```
CreateMap<SourceRecord, Record>()
.ForMember(x=>x.Property,config=>config.MapFrom<PropertyResolver>)
.ConstructUsing(source=> new Record(string.Empty))
```

Note that you can use default values as arguments for the constructor's parameters, Automapper will still correctly map all other properties.

I hope this helps someone, or future me, when I run into this problem again.